# Do it more precise or more precisely?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

What is the right way to say it: "Do it more precise!" or "Do it more precisely!"? Are both correct?

[Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=more%20precise%2Cmore%20precisely&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cmore%20precise%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmore%20precise%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMore%20precise%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cmore%20precisely%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmore%20precisely%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMore%20precisely%3B%2Cc0) has both "more precise" and "more precisely" at equal frequencies, with "precisely" being more popular in the last 20 years.

[image]

Comment: You've compared apples and oranges in your Ngram: *more precise* usually modifies a noun, whereas *more precisely* usually modifies a verb (but sometimes an adjective). But your sentence has *more precise* incorrectly modifying a verb. Nonetheless, +1 for including your research effort in the question, even if it was faulty - doing so helps ensure that the answer can address both the substance of the question and logic behind it. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those two phrases are not equivalent. You can say "make it more precise" or "do it more precisely." The first uses an adjective, the second an adverb.

When you poll "do it more precise" on the NGram Viewer, you get a big zero. No instances.

The Viewer is [a flawed tool to begin with](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2469/should-we-allow-google-ngrams-to-be-presented-as-statistical-evidence-without-qu), but if you don't define your terms within a narrow enough scope, you'll get gibberish.